# Verificar si una Celda de una JTable está Vacia

Tags: java

Buenas tardes,
Estoy intentando pasar el contenido de 2 JTextFields en 2 celdas de una JTable al apretar un botón.
Para eso realice un método que se supone verifica si una tabla esta vacía y por consiguiente agrega los valores en la misma fila , diferente columna.
Tengo declarada una Tabla de 10 Rows vacías y el código que genere para verificar si una celda está vacía es la siguiente:

```
public void PasarTextFieldATabla(JTable j, JTextField t1, JTextField t2) {

    int fila = 10;

    if (t1.getText().length() > 0 && t2.getText().length() > 0) {

        for(int i = 1; i<fila; i++ ) {

            if(j != null) {

                j.setValueAt(t1.getText(), i, 1);
                j.setValueAt(t2.getText(), i, 2);
            }

        }

    }

}
```

El evento del Boton es:

```
    btnIngresar.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {

            PasarTextFieldATabla(tablaValIng,txtPuntoX,txtPuntoFx);

        }
    });
```

La tabla esta creada para campos Float.

Como veo que al apretar el evento del Botón, no hace el pasaje del contenido de los textFields a la tabla, lo debuguie, y sale el siguiente error :

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a
>   Number    at java.text.DecimalFormat.format(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.text.Format.format(Unknown Source)   at
>   javax.swing.JTable$DoubleRenderer.setValue(Unknown Source)    at
>   javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(Unknown
>   Source)   at javax.swing.JTable.prepareRenderer(Unknown Source)   at
>   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paintCell(Unknown Source)     at
>   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paintCells(Unknown Source)    at
>   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paint(Unknown Source)     at
>   javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI.update(Unknown Source)   at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(Unknown Source)     at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)  at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(Unknown Source)   at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(Unknown
>   Source)   at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(Unknown
>   Source)   at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)     at
>   javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(Unknown Source)  at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(Unknown Source)   at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(Unknown Source)  at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown
>   Source)   at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown
>   Source)   at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(Unknown
>   Source)   at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1200(Unknown Source)   at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

Realmente desconozco que puede estar mal.
Agradezco toda ayuda o sugerencia para poder solucionarlo.

Comment: Si la tabla esta creada para float intenta poner en setValueAt(Float.parseFloat(t1.getText()), i, 1)

Comment: Muchas Gracias!!! Era el formato como vos decias Sr1871.

Comment: Pongo la resupuesta por si alguien tiene la misma duda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si la tabla esta creada para float, el valor ingresado debe ser float

`setValueAt(Float.parseFloat(t1.getText()), i, 1);`